# Log In from an appliction that is connected to a server

Tags: c++, vb.net, authentication, server, vps

I want to code a sort of application where you would login and it gets the data from a VPS or a Dedicated server, where i can create accounts, and it checks if the password and username are correct, if they are correct, the form will close and another form wil pop up. Can someone help me please? It doesnt matter for me if it is coded in C++ or VB.Net.

Comment: Using which protocol?

Answer (score 0):

first you need to have a database in the server to check the user name and password

search mysql 
http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/linux/sql/ch13_01.htm
then when you create the database then you can check you data.